# I cannot reboot my computer

Tags: reboot

I have a Samsung 540 notebook which has Windows 8 installed. I have the following message on my screen: `All boot options are tried. Press <F4> key to recover with factory image using Recovery or any other keys for next boot loop iteration.`

This post was on another question. I followed this but my computer still brings me back to the main screen.

"This post on social.msdn.microsoft.com mentions that error. An answer says that the problem is the "secure boot" setting. Go to BIOS, choose "Boot", and then disable "Secure Boot". Then change OS Mode Selection to CSM and UEFI OS. After you finish, exit choose "save changes/configuration and reset."

If you know how to solve this, please send me a message on here.

Comment: Sounds like you already know how to solve it

Comment: I do not. The advise above does not work.

Comment: Which Windows versions installed/shipped? Which notebook(?) exactly?

Comment: It is a Samsung 540 notebook which has Windows 8 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I know that being able to quickly reboot is nice - but shutting it down and turning it on again is really that big of a workaround?

If you want to quick-reboot, you can always hold the off-key for a while and press it again. But that's kind of a dirty solution.

Then again, I'm not fully comprehending your question maybe. Do you mean boot or reboot? If you mean reboot, this happens when you shut-down or when you boot up again? If it's when your starting up, there's something really weird with your MBR going on, I think.

Comment: Did you only read the title of the question? This clearly doesn't answer the question.